# Expectation and Variance of Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1]$, and $Y = X^2$.

a) Find $E(Y|X > 1/2)$

b) FInd $Var(Y|X > 1/2)$

I know what the distribution of X looks like, but I'm not sure what the distribution of Y looks like.

If X holds a value of $1$ from $[0,1]$, what would this squared look like? I feel like it would just look like X. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bad misunderstanding. $X$ does not "hold a value of one from $[0,1]$." You are confusing the random variable $X$ (which is a random number that can take any value in $[0,1]$) with its PDF (which is a constant function on $[0,1]$ with $f_X(x) = 1$).

Consequently, squaring $X$ is not the same thing as squaring its PDF. It means you take whatever comes out of the 'random number generator' (in this case an number drawn uniformly from the interval $[0,1]$) and square it. Since squaring makes all numbers in $[0,1]$ smaller, $Y$ is going to be more likely to be close to zero than close to one. In other words, it won't be uniform.

We can calculate this precisely. First observe that since $X$ is uniform, the probability that $X\le x$ for some $x\in [0,1]$ must be $x.$ That way, the probability that $X\in[0,1/2]$ is $1/2$ and the probability that $X\in[0,1/3]$ is $1/3$ like you expect. This means the CDF is $$ F_X(x)=P(X\le x) = x.$$

We can easily compute the CDF of $Y$ as follows: $$ F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(X^2 \le y) = P(X\le \sqrt{y}) = \sqrt{y}$$ where in the last step we used that $P(X\le x)=x.$

If you want the PDF $f_Y(y)$, it is the derivative of the CDF. Like $X,$ $Y$ is supported on $[0,1]$ (i.e. it can only take values in $[0,1]$).

Note: This addresses the question you asked of what $Y$ looks like... not the problem it was attached to, which has the additional complication of conditioning on $X.$ But note that $X>1/2$ is the same event as $Y>1/4.$

Comment: Thanks for the insight, breaking it down to CDF and PDF helps greatly.

Answer (score 1):

$X^2$ certainly does not have the same distribution as $X$.   Just examine the graph of $y=x^2$ and consider same length increments in $x$ near $0$ and $1$ and the size of the increments in $y$ to which they map.

Find the probability density function for $X^2$ using the chain rule (since a probability denstity function is the unsigned derivative of the cummulative distribution function).

$$\begin{align}f_X(x)&=\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1]}\\f_{X^2}(y) &= \left\lvert \dfrac{\mathrm d~ \surd y}{\mathrm d~ y~~~}\cdot f_X(\surd y)\right\rvert\\ &~\ddots \phantom{\tfrac 1{2\surd y}\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1]}} \end{align}$$

Or completely ignore that red herring and use the Law of the Unconcious Statatitian.

$$\mathsf E(g(X)\mid X\in A) =\int_{A} g(x)\cdot f_X(x)~\mathrm d x$$